# Haskell's head tail init and last in GHCi

Tags: list, haskell, types, ghci, type-constraints

I have a question about `head`, `tail`, `init` and `last`.
The following works in GHCi:

```
Prelude Data.List Data.Char> let n = [1..10] in (head n : tail n)
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

As expected, I get the whole list. So this should work for `init` and `last` too,
right?

```
Prelude Data.List Data.Char> let n = [1..10] in (init n : last n)

<interactive>:39:1:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Enum [[a]]
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
      it :: forall a. (Enum a, Enum [[a]], Num a, Num [[a]]) => [[a]]
```

If I look at the type signatures for the functions, then `head` and `last`
look the same -- they both return an element. Also `init` and `tail` look
the same, because they both return lists.

```
Prelude Data.List Data.Char> :info head
head :: [a] -> a        -- Defined in ‘GHC.List’
Prelude Data.List Data.Char> :info tail
tail :: [a] -> [a]      -- Defined in ‘GHC.List’
Prelude Data.List Data.Char> :info init
init :: [a] -> [a]      -- Defined in ‘GHC.List’
Prelude Data.List Data.Char> :info last
last :: [a] -> a        -- Defined in ‘GHC.List’
```

So what does `Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Enum [[a]]` mean?
If I do `init n` or `last n` without the construction of a new list, I get 
`[1..9]` and `10`.

Comment: Turns out you can't delete a comment?!

Comment: That's an absolutely terrible error message. The type checker ran into a more subtle problem first and reported it instead of getting to the real point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is true that `head`/`last` and `tail`/`init` have identical types. So if you had simply swapped out `last` for `head` and `init` for `tail`, you would have had no problem:

```
> let n = [1..10] in last n : init n
[10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

But you didn't. You did both that swap *and another*: you changed the order of arguments to `:`. It so happens that `:` doesn't take two arguments of the same type:

```
> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

So this last swap is not okay! In fact, if you give `n` a slightly more specific type signature, ghci will give a better error:

```
> let n :: [Integer]; n = [1..10] in init n : last n

<interactive>:1:50:
    Couldn't match type ‘Integer’ with ‘[[Integer]]’
    Expected type: [[[Integer]]]
      Actual type: [Integer]
    In the first argument of ‘last’, namely ‘n’
    In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘last n’
```

This error is still not 100% clear, but I think with a bit of puzzling you can see what it's complaining about: since `init n :: [Integer]`, and `(:) :: [Integer] -> [[Integer]] -> [[Integer]]`, it's expecting `last n :: [[Integer]]` and therefore `n :: [[[Integer]]]`. But you explicitly said `n :: [Integer]`, a conflict.

Now, what about the error it actually gave you in your case? Well, the clue is in the type of `[1..10]`:

```
> :t [1..10]
[1..10] :: (Enum t, Num t) => [t]
```

Notice that `[1..10]` is polymorphic. Moreover, it is used twice in your expression, and so it can be given *separate* monomorphic types in the two uses. So `[1..10]` is instantiated with *two* different types in the sequel!

Now I think you can start to see where the error you got comes in. It's trying to find a type `a` for which:

- `Enum a` -- this is needed to do the `..` part of `init [1..10]`
- `Num a` -- this is needed to do the `1` and `10` parts of `init [1..10]`
- `Enum [[a]]` -- if `init n :: a`, then to have `init n : last n` be well-typed, we must have `last n :: [a]` and hence the second occurrence of `n` must have `n :: [[a]]`; then the `Enum` constraint is needed for the `..` part of `last [1..10]`
- `Num [[a]]` -- by similar reasoning, this is needed to do the `1` and `10` parts of `last [1..10]`

But these constraints together are hard to satisfy -- certainly there's no instance of `Enum` and `Num` for lists in scope in the `Prelude` or `Data.List`. So it complains.

Answer (score 10):

Ahh snap, `:` takes an element and the rest like in `x:xs`, not a list and the last element, like in `xs:x`.

```
Prelude Data.List Data.Char> :info :  
data [] a = ... | a : [a] >·-- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
infixr 5 : 

data [] a = ... | a : [a] >·-- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
infixr 5 :
```

**I still would like to know how you understand GHCi error messages and I have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer anyway.**

Edit: I get that `x` and `xs` are only variable names chosen by convention, and `(xs:_)` would match the head but is unconventionally/confusingly named.

Edit 2: I upvoted and accepted Daniel Wagner's answer, because he explained the error message step by step. Really nice! Thank you!

Comment: (Better to avoid gendered language altogether in this context, I think. I have a gender, but not everyone does. Also, "girls" can be seen as disrespectful to women.)

Comment: You should probably edit this answer, so that it *reads* like an answer. Writing `:t (:)` in GHCi yields `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. But you are passing it a `[a]` as the first arg, and an `a` as second.

Answer (score 2):

In larger programs there is more type information (implicit and explicit) allowing the compiler to do a better job inferring types than in one-line snippets provided to GHCi.  As a result, the errors you see in GHCi are not representative of what is typically observed when building a full program.

That said, it's no excuse for the awfulness that is the error you posted:

```
Prelude> let n = [1..10] in (init n : last n)

<interactive>:8:1:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Enum [[a]]
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
      it :: forall a. (Enum a, Enum [[a]], Num a, Num [[a]]) => [[a]]
```

So there is a lot of polymorphism involved in your own line.  You have lists of Num a (`Num a => [a]`) where the type variable `a` must itself be alist since you've used `: last n` where `last n :: [_] ~ a`.  So this, combined with the fact that `..` in list comprehension implies an enum, is how we got to the horrible message.

Let's look at the simpler case where we've told GHCi our list is of type `[Int]`:

```
Prelude> let n = [1..10] :: [Int] in (init n : last n)

<interactive>:7:44:
    Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘[[Int]]’
    Expected type: [[[Int]]]
      Actual type: [Int]
    In the first argument of ‘last’, namely ‘n’
    In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘last n’
```

Ahh, much better.  Column 44 is the `n` in `last n`.  It says that `last n :: Int`.  So the type of `init n :` when `init n :: [Int]` means our cons function type is `(:) :: [Int] -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]`.  But wait!  `[[Int]]` needed for the argument of `init n :` does not match `Int` provided by `last n`!

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks. However Daniel was 3min. faster. Have an upvote. :)

Comment: That's OK.  I'll take a few upvotes off of Daniel's desk to make up for it.